# Reasons you would not want to heat a crystal hydrate (Measurement of water content in hydrate)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I understand that some decompose under heat.

Some will form a different product, Such as CuSO4 becoming CuO if heated too much and we wouldn't recover all of the water.

Some, such as AlCl3 actually forms HCl instead of water and needs to be reacted with another compound first.

But what other reasons are there, specific to crystal hydrates? I need two reasons and I feel like I only have one so far as I would count both under decomposition.

Do some have a similar boiling point to water that I am not seeing? Would it be so low that we boil it off along with the water?

It looks like they are all stable and do not combust.

I'm very confused because all I see talks about decomposition. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: This is a lab on crystal hydrates to find the % water and the formula of the Hydrate. IE our sample turned out to be MgSO4 7H2O. The lab question is specifically why you wouldn't want to use heat to find the percentage of water in hydrated crystals. The question is phrased that heating is not the recommended method, give two reasons why not. I believe I have one reason, decomposition, but can't find anything else that would tell me why you shouldn't use heat. I've torn up two books and the internet just tells me decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is that it is sometimes difficult to be sure that all water have been removed by heating. For example, copper sulfate $\ce{CuSO4·5H2O}$ loses $\ce{4 H2O}$ at $110°$C. To get rid of the last water molecule, it is necessary to overheat it to about $200°$C.

Comment: This is already mentioned in my post. Just not in detail.

Comment: The decompositionof anhydrous $\ce{CuSO4}$  into $\ce{CuO}$ does happen at much higher temperatures, after all water has been released. And you have not spoken about copper sulfate crystallized with five molecules water.